# What software should I use to set up folder synchronization between Windows servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, windows, synchronization

I know many folder synchronization tools for desktop users (ie. [Windows Live Sync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Sync))

Should I use them to synchronize applications between servers or there is a more enterprisey solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using DFS?  It'll replicate files between servers (seeing as that's what it was designed for).

Comment: +1 - DFS Replication (DFS-R) does a great job.

Answer (score 4):

How are your servers connected? Have you tried Microsoft's own [Synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en)? Not sure if it's "enterprisey" enough for you, though :) For small shops it's working just fine.

Robocopy is another option

Comment: This SyncToy has a problem, if it tries to copy a file that is used by a running process it fails, but if you try to copy the same file using the windows explorer it succeds

Comment: +1 - love synctoy. Wasn't aware of its locked file problem though.